# Zero knowledge contingent payment on ethereum?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-design, contract-deployment

I know that bitcoin supports Zero-knowledge contingent payment (ZKCP), can ethereum support such ZKCP Payment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just learning that term, but I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes." From https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/02/26/zero-knowledge-contingent-payments-announcement/:

> So the buyer initially wanted to buy an input for his program, but now he would be just as happy to buy the preimage of a hash. As it turns out, Bitcoin already provides a way to sell hash preimages in a secure manner.

It's easy to make an Ethereum smart contract that pays a certain account if and only if it's provided with the preimage of some hash. Completely untested:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

contract BuyPreimage {
    address payable buyer;
    address payable seller;
    bytes32 public hash;
    uint256 public deadline;

    constructor(address payable _seller, bytes32 _hash, uint256 timeout) public payable {
        buyer = msg.sender;
        seller = _seller;

        hash = _hash;
        deadline = now + timeout;
    }

    // If this is called with the correct preimage, the seller gets paid.
    function providePreimage(bytes calldata preimage) external {
        require(keccak256(preimage) == hash);
        seller.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    // Issue a refund back to the buyer if the timeout has expired.
    function refund() external {
        require(msg.sender == buyer);
        require(now >= deadline);

        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the line `seller.transfer(address(this).balance);
` ? what is the balance word refere to ?

Comment: It's the balance of (amount of ether owned by) the given address. In this case, the contract.

Comment: @smarks: but in this way, the function transfer will transfer all the amount of ether that owned by the given address. I think the balance value should be predefined?

Comment: Yes, it will transfer the contract's entire balance. If you don't want that, you can put in some different amount.

Comment: I read that the after the buyer construct that smart contract with the deposit value, he can unlock this deposit and it can not be used anymore when calling provideimage function . How can that misbehaving prevented?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. Where did you read that? What do you mean by "unlock"?