# Is it okay to define the following smart contract that a accepts funds from two parties?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

I want to deploy a smart contract that receive funds from two parties. The contract is initialized with some ethers from person (call it *revealer*), and another Recipient (name it *fineRecipient*) who should aslo deposit an amount of ethers. If the revealer call the contract with the correct preimage of a certain hash value, he gets his funds back and also the Recipient deposit. *Otherwise*, the Recipient can get all funds in the contract. *Is the following contract is okay from security point of view ? or does it needs any modifications before testing it in real production environment?*

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

contract TimedCommitment {
    address payable revealer;
    address payable fineRecipient;
    bytes32 public hash;
    uint256 public deadline;

    constructor(address payable _fineRecipient, bytes32 _hash, uint256 timeout) public payable {
        revealer = msg.sender;
        fineRecipient = _fineRecipient;
        hash = _hash;
        deadline = now + timeout;
    }

  function  deposit(uint256 amount) payable public{
         require(msg.value == amount);
         require(msg.value == fineRecipient);

    }

    // If this is called with the correct preimage, the revealer gets their funds back.
    function providePreimage(bytes calldata preimage) external {
        require(keccak256(preimage) == hash);
        revealer.transfer(address(this).balance);
       revealer.transfer(address(this).amount);
    }

    // Pay the fine to the fineRecipient if the timeout has expired.
    function refund() external {
        require(msg.sender == fineRecipient);
        require(now >= deadline);

        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

This contract is edited from this nice answer :[timed commitment using ethereum blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65920/timed-commitment-using-ethereum-blockchain/65921#65921)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `providePreimage()`, you are trying to transfer the ether twice. This will cause a revert. As a result, revealer will never be able to provide preimage and transfer the ether back to itself. The timeout will eventually be reached and `fineRecipient` will be able to transfer funds to itself using `refund()`.

To fix the issue, change providePreimage() function to

```
function providePreimage(bytes calldata preimage) external {
    require(keccak256(preimage) == hash);
    revealer.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

As an added measure of security, you can add a condition that `fineRecipient` must deposit their share at least X time before timeout is reached so that `revealer` has enough time to reveal the preimage. If `fineRecipient` fails to do so, the `refund()` function should refund the `revealer` and not `fineRecipient`.